# HTTPS issues using cloudflare and ubuntu 16.04 LEMP WordPress

Tags: nginx, https, ubuntu-16.04, port-443

First, let me say that I am new to sysadmin stuff, and this is a site I am using to gain practice and experience.

I have an SSL through cloudflare, and i have uploaded it to `/var/ssl/ssl.pem` and `/var/ssl/ssl.key`. I changed the folder permissions to chmod 700 /var/ssl.

I can access my site via http://165.227.182.40/ and http://aaronstone.io/ but not https://aaronstone.io/

`sudo ufw status` returns:

```
WARN: / is group writable!
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

`netstat -atpn` shows

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1392/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6504/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60484         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 5338/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 165.227.182.40:22       63.131.219.239:58963    ESTABLISHED 5338/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:60484         ESTABLISHED 1392/mysqld
tcp        0    332 165.227.182.40:22       63.131.219.239:58846    ESTABLISHED 2096/sshd: aaron [p
tcp        0      0 165.227.182.40:80       108.162.216.205:14411   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60486         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 5338/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:60486         ESTABLISHED 1392/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6504/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1621/sshd
```

My NginX config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
         ssl_certificate /var/ssl/ssl.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/ssl/ssl.key;

    root /var/www/html/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name aaronstone.io www.aaronstone.io;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
             location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

nginx status:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-02-07 19:22:19 UTC; 14min ago
  Process: 6492 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
  Process: 5588 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, stat
  Process: 6500 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 6497 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status
 Main PID: 6504 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 3.5M
      CPU: 505ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─6504 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─6505 nginx: worker process

Feb 07 19:22:19 aaronstone systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Feb 07 19:22:19 aaronstone systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Inval
Feb 07 19:22:19 aaronstone systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: nginx isn't listening on port 443, so it must have issued an error message about that part of the configuration. What does the nginx error log say?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx **does not listen** to port 443, as your netstat output shows.
Your nginx config seems to be correct, in fact I tried it and it works for me. Do you have other webservers running? I suspect something running at port 80 (e.g. Apache/httpd) and nginx does not start up.

Does nginx start up without any error messages?

If you have nginx running as service, what is the output of `sudo service nginx status`?

If you add the parameter **p** to the netstat command, e.g. `sudo netstat -atpn`, it shows the process name of the listening addresses (see `man netstat` for more information). Does the line `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN` belong to nginx?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect. nginx seems to start fine, i dont have any issues editing my site. I just cannot access it via https.

Comment: Glad you could resolve your problem. The absence of any error message but a starting nginx indicated that the config was not actually enabled.

Comment: Thats a very good tip. I will remember that in the future as I was VERY confused.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had no symlink from `/sites-available` to `/sites-enabled`

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
$ sudo ln -sf ../sites-available/default .
$ sudo service nginx reload
```